# AngularJS: How do I communicate data from a service to a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frameworks

I'm a new to AngularJS and not terribly familiar with JavaScript.  I'm trying to make a simple app using AngularJS v1.3.15.

I have this controller:

```
var app = angular.module('game', [])
app.controller('SimpleController', ['market_data', function(market_data) {

    this.city_name = "City";
    market_data.success(function(data) {
        console.log(data.city_name);
        this.city_name = data.city_name;
    });
}]);
```

And this view:

```
<div ng-controller="SimpleController as simple" >
  <h1>Hello {{simple.city_name}}!</h1>
</div>
```

The city name line does not change from the default: `City`.

As far as I can tell, the service, `market_data` seems to be working great.  My call to `console.log` prints out the string that I expect to be returned by the service.  So, `data.city_name` contains the proper information, but `this.city_name` does not update the controller.

What's the best way to get this data into the controller so that it will show up in my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a local variable for `this`. `vm` (viewmodel) is commonly used.

```
var app = angular.module('game', [])
app.controller('SimpleController', ['market_data', function(market_data) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.city_name = "City";

    market_data.success(function(data) {
        console.log(data.city_name);
        vm.city_name = data.city_name;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there would be a way to do it without the `$scope` variable.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `this`, you have to save the value of city in `$scope`. like this

```
app.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', 'market_data', function($scope, market_data) {
    $scope.city_name = "City";
    market_data.success(function(data) {
        console.log(data.city_name);
        $scope.city_name = data.city_name;
    });
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
var app = angular.module('game', [])
app.controller('SimpleController', ['market_data', function(market_data) {

    $scope.city_name = "City";
    market_data.success(function(data) {
        console.log(data.city_name);
        $scope.city_name = data.city_name;
    });
}]);



<div ng-controller="SimpleController" >
  <h1>Hello {{simple.city_name}}!</h1>
</div>
```